# Unable to ssh in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am newbie to VS code.
I try to ssh the server in VS code.
I found how to ssh the server in VS code and follow those steps but I cannot ssh to the server.
The steps that I did in VS code is

1. Install VS code.
2. Install Remote - SSH in VS code from the extension.
3. I connect to HOST: ssh user@hostname
4. I select C:\Users\username.ssh\config
5. In config, I fill all the corresponding data of HOST, HOSTNAME, USERNAME
6. Then I tried either linux or window
7. I entered the password.

Those are the steps that I try to connect ssh to the server. But I cannot successfully ssh to the server. The error I got is

```
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /c (type "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-(hostname)" | ssh -T -D 56383 "(hostname)" bash) & exit /b 0" terminated with exit code: 255.
```

May I know do I miss any setting to successfully ssh to the server?
When I searched in internet, after giving the username@hostname and setting the configuration, it can ssh to the server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether cmd is working.

1. win + r
2. type "cmd", and Enter

if there are nothing, please check Registry:

1. win + r
2. regedit
3. check "\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor", set AutoRun to nothing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).